# How to hide root node from jsTree?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jstree

[#1] 
I want to hide root node from jstree ?

I appended few sub-root node to **"Root"** node so I want to hide root node from jsTree ?

[image]

After applying following CSS To hide root node , Look n feel issue came in IE8 :

```
    $("ul:contains('Root')").css('position','relative');
    $("ul:contains('Root')").css('top','-20px');
    $("ul:contains('Root')").css('left','-20px');
```

[image: CSS issue in IE8 to hide root node]

[#2] 
In following **core** plugin,

I provided hard coded value(**Root_ID**) for Root node to open Root node Initially, It works fine

```
"core" : { initially_open" : [ "Root_ID" ] }
```

Root nodes ID may vary RootID, RID, Root_id, R_ID..... as we are providing different xml response.

Psudo code something like:

```
"core" : { initially_open" : [ **1st_node_of_Tree_like_(ul > li:first)_OR_$(".jstree-last").first()** ] }
```

How I can achieve this 2 things?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

It's a little counterintuitive but best way to create a tree with no explicit root node is to not provide any root node in the data, and make all the children of the root node have parent "#".   jstree will render a tree with multiple top level children of the root.  Avoids any messiness with trying to hide the root.

Answer (score 3):

**I  found very Simple answer :)**

```
$("#treeViewDiv").bind("loaded.jstree", 
 function (event, data) {
       // To hide root nodes text
       $("a:contains('Root')").css("visibility","hidden")  
       // Need to find other way to hide rootNodeName Any1 knows ?

       // To hide - icon
       $(".jstree-last .jstree-icon").first().hide()
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't work with `"loaded.jstree"` for me (jstree-rails-4-3.2.1), `"ready.jstree"` is working.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("a:contains('Root')").css("visibility","hidden")
```

or

```
$("a:contains('Root')").css("display","none")
```

maybe there is also an option in jsTree, but i am not familar with that lib.

**Update:**

assuming your jsTree is in some kind of div, try moving it until Root Element is hidden:

```
$("ul:contains('Root')").css('position','relative');
$("ul:contains('Root')").css('top','-20px');
$("ul:contains('Root')").css('left','-20px');
```

You may have to edit the css selector(`"ul:contains('Root')"`) to get the right `ul`. Also you might want to edit the amount you move `top` and `left`

Comment: Thanks for reply :) Only "Root" name is hidden. "-" icon is not hidden. I want to hide both i.e + Root. <ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins> is used by jsTree to show - icon. How to hide - icon related to root node ?

Comment: Thanks both things are working fine :) . [#1] Provided css is valid for all browser ? [#2]Is there any way to avoid hard-coded value("Root") mentioned in example, while hiding Root node[icon and rootNodeName]. It may happen Root name may changes time to time. In that case how to ?

Comment: answer is useful :) I will accept this answer only when if we can able to remove hardcoded value as mentioned in above comment :)

Comment: After applying provided css to hide root node. Look n feel issue came in only IE8. See updated question + 2nd Image added

Comment: just make sure the surrounding div has overflow:hidden set in css

Comment: I set css : overflow:hidden to Outer DIV :: facing same issur : Not working.... :(

Comment: well, you might try and check that the css z-level of the jsTree is lower than that of the surrounding div. other than that it's hard to tell from here. is it possible that you upload a demo to jasfiddle? maybe also draw a simple div in your Outer DIV and try to hide that first, to make sure you have no other issues.

Comment: what about hardcoded value ? How we can eliminate hard coded value like "Root"

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked (at least in Chrome and Firefox), for me, is:

```
#root>ins, #root>a{
    display: none;
}

ul>#root{
    position: relative;
    /*top: -20px;*/
    left: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourTreeDiv").on("loaded.jstree", function(e, data) {
    $("#yourTreeDiv > ul > li > i.jstree-icon").remove();
    $("#yourTreeDiv > ul > li > a.jstree-anchor").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS:

```
.on('after_open.jstree', function(e, data){
        var a = $('#file_tree').find('i');
        $(a[0]).hide();
        $(a[1]).hide();
    })
```

in css:

```
.jstree {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 100%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```